# onValueChange of textfield is not triggered when selecting an option from exposed dropdownMenu composable, jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-compose-exposeddropdown

I am trying to implement an exposed dropdown composable which I can use in multiple parts of my android jetpack compose app. Whenever I select an item from the dropdownMenu the selectedOption is set in the composable and assigned to the textfield value displaying the correct item. However the onValueChange event of the Textfield displaying the result is not fired. This causes the state not being updated in the viewmodel layer of my app. Following my code of my composable.

```
// ExposedDropdownComposable.kt    
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun PlantExposedSelect(
  options: List<String>,
  optionSelected: String,
  label: String,
  onOptionSelected: (String) -> Unit,
  onFocusChange: (FocusState) -> Unit,
) {
  var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(optionSelected) }
  ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = {
      expanded = !expanded
    }

  ) {
    TextField(
      readOnly = true,
        value = selectedOption,
      onValueChange = onOptionSelected
      label = { Text(label) },
      trailingIcon = {
        ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
          expanded = expanded
        )
      },
      colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .onFocusChanged {
          onFocusChange(it)
        },
    )
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
      expanded = expanded,
      onDismissRequest = {
        expanded = false
      }
    ) {
      options.forEach { selectOption ->
        DropdownMenuItem(
          onClick = {
            selectedOption = selectOption
            expanded = false
            Log.e("selectEdoption", selectedOption)
          }
        ) {
          Text(text = selectOption)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code where I use the composable in my AddPlantsScreen

```
PlantExposedSelect(
  options = options,
  optionSelected = lightState.text,
  label = lightState.hint,
  onOptionSelected = {
    Log.e("eventValue", it)
    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditPlantEvent.EnteredLight(it))
  },
  onFocusChange = {
    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditPlantEvent.ChangedLightFocus(it))
  },
)
```

How do I make the  onClick event of the dropdownItem, trigger the onValueChange event of the Textfield dislaying the selectedOption.

Comment: Use the the `onClick` in the `DropdownMenuItem` to update the viewmodel

Comment: can you pls elaborate how to use it? when i try to add a line with:
onValueChange inside the onClick block my IDE shows me an error

Comment: Just call `onOptionSelected` in the `onClick`

Comment: thanks this worked you can post as answer if you want, was even able to get rid of selectedOption variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the `onOptionSelected` in the `onClick` parameter of the `DropdownMenuItem` instead of using the `onValueChange`.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun PlantExposedSelect(
  //...
  onOptionSelected: (String) -> Unit,
) {
  var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(optionSelected) }

  ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    //....
  ) {
    TextField(
      value = selectedOption,
      onValueChange = {},   //remove the function
      //...
    )
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
      /** ... **/
      }
    ) {
      options.forEach { selectOption ->
        DropdownMenuItem(
          onClick = {
            selectedOption = selectOption
            expanded = false
            onOptionSelected         //update your viewmodel here
          }
        ) {
          Text(text = selectOption)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [hoist](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) the selected option state like this,

```
val (optionSelected, setOptionSelected)= remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
} 

PlantExposedSelect(
    options = options,
    optionSelected = optionSelected,
    label = "Label",
    onOptionSelected = {
        Log.e("eventValue", it)
        setOptionSelected(it)
        // viewModel.onEvent(AddEditPlantEvent.EnteredLight(it))
    },
    onFocusChange = {
        // viewModel.onEvent(AddEditPlantEvent.ChangedLightFocus(it))
    },
)
```

And replace `selectedOption` in `PlantExposedSelect` with `optionSelected`.

---

**Complete code for reference**

```
@Composable
fun PlantExposedSelectSample() {
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4")
    val (optionSelected, setOptionSelected)= remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    PlantExposedSelect(
        options = options,
        optionSelected = optionSelected,
        label = "Label",
        onOptionSelected = {
            Log.e("eventValue", it)
            setOptionSelected(it)
            // viewModel.onEvent(AddEditPlantEvent.EnteredLight(it))
        },
        onFocusChange = {
            // viewModel.onEvent(AddEditPlantEvent.ChangedLightFocus(it))
        },
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun PlantExposedSelect(
    options: List<String>,
    optionSelected: String,
    label: String,
    onOptionSelected: (String) -> Unit,
    onFocusChange: (FocusState) -> Unit,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }

    ) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = optionSelected,
            onValueChange = onOptionSelected,
            label = {
                Text(label)
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = expanded
                )
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onFocusChanged {
                    onFocusChange(it)
                },
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }
        ) {
            options.forEach { selectOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        onOptionSelected(selectOption)
                        expanded = false
                        Log.e("selectEdoption", selectOption)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = selectOption)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```